# Why is the Lodash _.find method returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have a collection and using the Lodash `_.find` method, I want to return the object with the title matching "Development".

So I have the following code which I had hoped would return what I wanted:

```
// Define rooms
var rooms = [
  { title: 'Just For Fun', created: '2016-10-23T16:57:03.288Z', id: 2 },
  { title: 'Development', created: '2016-10-23T16:57:03.294Z', id: 6 }
];
// Load lodash module
var _ = require('lodash');
// Expected object for development?
console.log(_.find(rooms, {'id': 6}));
```

However, what I get back in the console is simply `undefined`. The [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#find) has the following example:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];
// The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
_.find(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true });
// => object for 'pebbles'
```

So they get `pebbles` but I get `undefined`? Can anyone indicate where I am going wrong here? Thanks in advance!

I am using Node.

Comment: (1) Can you show your code in one code block, so the order is clear? Have you defined `room` before doing the `_.find`? (2) how have you installed lodash? (3) which version of Node are you running on?

Comment: @trincot I see what you're getting at but I was indeed defining rooms before the console.log(). Have updated my question.

Comment: You know of course that `console.log` itself returns undefined so that will be output to the console. The line above that should be the element it found. Usually screen shots are a bad idea but in this case it might be useful.

Comment: @torazaburo The proof is in the pudding, was going to make a screen shot when I realized that I had encapsulated the id as a string in my test and in the example here on SO it is an integer. That is the problem, thanks for your help! ;/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working. The console.log might be confusing you:

```
var rooms = [
  { title: 'Just For Fun', created: '2016-10-23T16:57:03.288Z', id: 2 },
  { title: 'Development', created: '2016-10-23T16:57:03.294Z', id: 6 }
];
var room = _.find(rooms, {'id': 6});
console.log(room); // Object {title: "Development", created: "2016-10-23T16:57:03.294Z", id: 6}
```

Comment: @CraigvanTonder, Why do you say "it works" for this answer, while you say it gives you "undefined" for the other equivalent answer? And how does this differ from the code you tried with?

Comment: @trincot I am no expert but simply put, if I console log the Lodash method the result is undefined, however if I define a variable as being the result of the Loadash method then console log the variable then it outputs the object as I had intended. Maybe you could explain this to me? :s

Comment: Have you altered the `room` variable afterwards? That could explain it, because `console.log` does not always evaluate the expression value synchronously.

Comment: @trincot Simply put, I am a moron... In my test I encapsulated the id as a string but it should actually be an integer as in my question.... Thank you for providing the extra insight on this matter, I appreciate it!

Comment: Good that you found it. In that case the question can be closed (or deleted, which you can do yourself).